# How to validate a form step-by-step (3 steps) into a carousel?

Tags: javascript, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I need build a form in three steps inside a carousel. I'm using the bootstrap to create the site but I dont know how to validate one step of my form without submit the data and after show the second step (or second slide) to the user continue filling the form up to the third step (or third slide) when he can submit the data. Someone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You might just want to validate the fields of the form locally.

You can just bind the `onsubmit` event listener to the form element, which will be trigger when user submit the data. As you want to validate the form step-by-step, you just need to validate the current step's fields in each step, that you should use `event.preventDefault()` to stop submitting the data in step one and step two. The code may like:

```
ndForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    if (!checkSteps()) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Or you can validate the field immediately after the user modify it; e.g. attach the `onblue` event listener to the text field to handle user's input.

I prefer the first way since the code is much clearer and more maintainable.